# base url dont work on typo3 6.2

Tags: typo3

i have problem after installing the bootstrap package on my localhost wamp

```
http://localhost/fileadmin/bsdist/lib/bootstrap/3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css?1419681956
```

i have added config.baseURL

```
baseURL  = http://localhost/typo3/
```

Answer (score 0):

`/typo3/` is the admin panel you can't set that URL as baseURL. I don't you what happen but i think he will remove that part.

So set your Domain as baseURL and don't forget the `/` at the end.

```
baseURL  = http://localhost/
```

don't forget to clear your complete cache to load the changes.

Comment: Thank you, sorry i didn't be clear, i just named my project folder typo3 like typo3project.

Answer (score 0):

As @Stony already pointed you cannot use `.../typo3/` as baseURL because this is location specific for TYPO3's backend.

On the other hand working with TYPO3 in subfolders always rises some problems as you need to change several configs (i.e. in `.htaccess` for url rewriting) to make it working correctly. And as I last tested clean installation in subfolder doesn't work as expected out-of-the-box.

Fortunately there's simple and elegant solution - creating custom *domain* locally.

- Just in your **hosts** file add line like

  ```
   127.0.0.1   myproject.loc
  ```
- Add a `vhost` for this `myproject.loc` in your Apache config
- Restart Apache and flush the DNS cache

In such case your project will be available locally at url `http://myproject.loc/` so you can use it as well as your `baseURL`

Comment: Thank you very much biesior, it is so useful :)

Answer (score 0):

If the typo3 installation is not in the domain's root directory, you must modify the RewriteBase in the default htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /<project_directory>
```

In your case:

```
RewriteBase /typo3
```